# Visual Studio Setting label text from another class C#

Tags: visual-studio

I have read some answers and some tutorials but they either didn't work or were too complex for me to understand.
I am trying to get a different class to change A labels text but It did not work. Here is my code:

```
public static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Mainprog mp = new Mainprog();
    Mainprog.count += 25;
    mp.Counter.Text = Convert.ToString(Mainprog.count);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a System.Timers.Timer instead of using a Windows.Forms.Timer. The timer you are using runs on a separate thread so you will need to use Invoke to access an UI object, the Windows.Forms.Timer doesn't. I also presume you are getting an error of some sort please add it to your question.

Comment: I am not getting any error from my code. Is there suppose to be one or am I missing something?